# How to move data automatically to another collection when certain number of records in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to MongoDB. I want to move 1-day data from `collectionA` to `collection-date` (this `collection-date` name has to create dynamically) automatically every day. The moved records should not avail in `collectionA`. Is this possible in mongodb?

Comment: Can I ask why you are putting your data in separate collections like this? There are lots of disadvantages to that approach, compared to putting them in a single collection with a suitable indexed date field for example.

Comment: Hi vince, actually for every day there will be 1 million of records. so when i am accessing this data, it is taking lot time even though we have indexed for that collection. it is giving us performance issues in production. So kindly help me out any way to solve this issue

Comment: Hi All, still i am waiting for your kind reply.

 Thanks in adavance.